# IronPython, IronRuby, IronScheme, IronSomething

Tags: .net, clr

why some languages that targets .net platform has Iron- as a prefix? It seems like such convention only applies to non-microsoft developed languages.

Comment: This has been asked previously.

Comment: Not sure it's on-topic for StackOverflow, but it's interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a convention for implementation of dynamic languages which run on CLR (actually [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx)). IIRC, it is an acronym for 'I Run On .NET ...', so more or less a catchy name which turned into convention. I think it was IronPython which started it, but I am not 100% sure.